# Using `MatchPhrasePrefix` in query DSL of Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, querydsl

I am new to Elasticsearch.

Can someone please explain why this search (`NEST 6`):

```
var searchResponse1 = this.elasticClient.Search<dynamic>(
    s => s.AllTypes().AllIndices().IgnoreUnavailable().Size(100).From(0)
        .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.SimpleQueryString(c => c.Query("query"))))));
```

correctly results in the following request (I got this using Fiddler):

```
POST https://someUrl.com/_search?pretty=true&error_trace=true&typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=true HTTP/1.1
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "query"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 100
}
```

But both of the following searches for 'MatchPhrasePrefix':

```
var searchResponse2 = this.elasticClient.Search<dynamic>(
    s => s.AllTypes().AllIndices().IgnoreUnavailable().Size(100).From(0)
        .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.MatchPhrasePrefix(c => c.Query("query"))))));

var searchResponse3 = this.elasticClient.Search<dynamic>(
    s => s.AllTypes().AllIndices().IgnoreUnavailable().Size(100).From(0)
        .Query(q => q.MatchPhrasePrefix(p => p.Query("query"))));
```

result in:

```
POST https://someUrl.com/_search?pretty=true&error_trace=true&typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=true HTTP/1.1
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MatchPhrasePrefix` query **must** also specify a field to target. For example

```cs
var searchResponse2 = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
    .AllTypes()
    .AllIndices()
    .IgnoreUnavailable()
    .Size(100)
    .From(0)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m
                .MatchPhrasePrefix(c => c
                    .Field("some_field") // <-- target the "some_field" field
                    .Query("query")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which results in the query

```
POST /_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "some_field": {
              "query": "query"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 100
}
```

Without specifying the field, the query is considered *conditionless* in the client, and will be omitted from the response. There's [an issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/4050) to discuss whether *conditionless* queries should be removed in the next major version.

Comment: so there is no way to target all the fields, right?

Comment: In 6.x, if you have the `_all` field enabled (whihc may be the case for an index upgraded from 5.x), or have configured your own `copy_to` field, you can target this field: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/mapping-all-field.html.